# Server.MapPath() at remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have seen the differences between Server.MapPath() and HostingEnvironment.MapPath().

But I cant understand why I am getting this strange behavior -

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MapPath("~/Data/File.txt")
```

is working fine, locally and when the site is hosted in IIS on the local machine.

But when I publish to a remote server it fails. And using

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Data/File.txt")
```

fixes the problem.

What is really going on here?

Comment: Different version of IIS/asp.net on the remote machine perhaps?

Comment: just to be clear, what exactly is the failure? I'm assuming it's that it can't find the file, but just in case... . And have you debugged to compare what strings are produced by the two methods, precisely? maybe it would give some clue.

Comment: See exception first.